# Is the conditional "if(x)" different than "if(x == true)"?

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

I'm wondering what the core difference is between the conditional syntax below?

```
if (something) {
    // do something
}
```

vs.

```
if (something == true) {
    // do something
}
```

Are there any differences?

**Edit:** I apologize. I made a typo when the question was asked. I did not mean to put a triple equals sign. I know that triple equals is a strict operator. I was meaning to ask if '==' is the equivalent of if (something).

Comment: You've completely changed the meaning of the question by changing `===` to `==`. Edit: Now someone has changed it back... @W3Geek: What did you actually intend?

Comment: Yes, I made a typo. I meant to say double equals. I know what triple equals is... Its a strict operator. I already know there is a difference between them.

Comment: Personally, I write if (a === true) if I need to check a known boolean and if (a !== null && a !== undefined) to test if (a). I think if (a) could mean too many things.... For instance, if a is 0 then if(a) will evaluate to false....

Comment: I messed up this thread so bad by making a typo. :(

Comment: Yeah I just noticed that. `=]` Removed the previous comment. +1 @pst

Comment: For those voting to close, he was not asking about `===`, but his question kept getting edited by others.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**EDIT: Below only holds true for the original question, in which the `===` operator was used.**

The first one will execute the body of the if-statement if `something` is "truthy" while the second will only execute it if it is equal in type and value to `true`.

So, what is "truthy"? To understand that, you need to know what is its opposite: falsey. All values in JavaScript will be coerced into a Boolean value if placed in a conditional expression. Here's a list of falsey values:

- `false`
- `0` (zero)
- `""` (empty string)
- `null`
- `undefined`
- `NaN`

All other values are truthy, though I've probably missed some obscure corner case that someone will point out in the comments.

**Here's my answer to the updated question:**

<del>The conditional `if (something)` and `if (something == true)` are equivalent, though the second is redundant. `something` will be type coerced in the same way in either case.</del> This is wrong. See [Felix Kling's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11852927/218196).

Comment: +1 for 'truthy'. I meant '=='. Is it equivalent to if (something)?

Comment: Sadly, this is no longer exactly correct, now that the OP has specified that he meant `==` instead of `===`.

Comment: I prefer the first way, but to each their own.

Comment: They are not equivalent! See my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/11852927/218196

Comment: @Felix Kling - You have disproven me. JavaScript!!

Answer (score 13):

The difference is that in `if(something)`, [`something` is evaluated as boolean](http://es5.github.com/#x12.5). It is basically

```
if(ToBoolean(something))
```

where [`ToBoolean`](http://es5.github.com/#x9.2) is an internal function that is called to convert the argument to a boolean value. You can simulate `ToBoolean` with a double [negation](http://es5.github.com/#x11.4.9): `!!something`.

In the second case, [both operands are (eventually) converted to numbers first](http://es5.github.com/#x11.9.3), so you end up with

```
if(ToNumber(something) == ToNumber(true))
```

which can lead to very different results. Again, [`ToNumber`](http://es5.github.com/#x9.3) is an internal function. It can be simulated (to some degree) using the [unary plus operator](http://es5.github.com/#x11.4.6): `+something == +true`. In the actual algorithm, `something` is first passed  [`ToPrimitive`](http://es5.github.com/#x9.1) if `something` is an object.

---

**Example**:

Assume that

```
var something = '0'; // or any other number (not 0) / numeric string != 1
```

`if(something)` will be `true`, since `'0'` is a non-empty string.

`if(something == true)` will be `false`, since `ToNumber('0')` is `0`, `ToNumber(true)` is `1` and `0 == 1` is `false`.

Comment: +1 This is the closest thing to a correct answer. The only thing I would add is that `ToBoolean` and `ToNumber` are not exposed directly as functions in JavaScript. Calling the `Number` constructor as a function, or using the unary `+` operator are equivalent though.

Comment: @Matthew: Thanks, I clarified it.

Comment: Great answer. Out of curiosity, in your answer, you say "where `ToBoolean` is an internal function that is called to convert the argument to a boolean value". Is there a reason that you used `ToBoolean` instead of the `Boolean()` function?

Comment: @Jacob: That's just what the spec uses when evaluating the condition of an `if` statement. I could have used `Boolean` just as well.

Answer (score 3):

`if(something)` is equivalent to `if(someting == true)`.

The `==` operator checks for equality while `===` checks for sameness.  In this case, any truthy value will cause the condition to be met for the first one, but only `true` will cause the condition to be met for the second one.

**EDIT: Felix Kling's answer is correct.  Please reference that instead.**

Comment: +1 for answering both the intended question *and* the original question.

Comment: They are not equivalent! See my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11852927/218196

Answer (score 2):

Now that the question has changed from `===` to `==`, no, there is no practical difference.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple ways to look at it. The first example evaluates to see if "something" has a true-like or positive value. So as long as it is not 0, negative, null, or empty it should evaluate the contents of that if statement.

In your second statement you are testing to see if "something" is the equivalent of boolean true. Another words "TRUE" or 1. You could also do a "===" comparison so that it has to be identical to what your comparing it to. So in this case if you did something === true then "something" would have to be boolean true, the value of 1 would not suffice.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between the two conditions `thing == true` and just `thing`.

There is a large difference between `thing === true` and just `thing`, however.

In javascript, values are coerced to a boolean when they are put in a condition. This means all values of all types must be able to be coerced to either `true` or `false`. A value that coerces to `true` is generally called "truthy", and a value that coerces to `false` is called "falsey".

The "falsey" values are as follows:

- `NaN` (not a number)
- `''` (empty string)
- `undefined`
- `null`
- `0` (numeric 0)

Everything else evaluates to `true` when coerced. [This jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QjSYG/9/) will help you keep track of what is "truthy" and what is "falsey".

The identity operator (`===`) does NOT perform any type coercion: if the types are different, the comparison immediately fails.